# Having trouble with Youtube status code 429, can't seem to fix

Tags: npm, youtube, discord, discord.js, distube

I created a discord music bot using the distube package and I keep getting this error everytime I try to play a song. After doing some searching, it seems that I need a Youtube Cookie and I was able to get mine successfully and it worked for a test bot that I have. However, when I used the same cookie in my main bot, then I get this error. My test bot works fine now, but my main bot doesn't and im wondering if anyone could help me. This would be greatly appreciated!

```
MinigetError: play(armed and dangerous) encountered:
Status code: 429
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/runner/HMS-Bot/node_modules/miniget/dist/index.js:203:31)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:601:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:122:17)
    at HTTPParser.execute (<anonymous>)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:474:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12) {
  statusCode: 429
}
```

Comment: [Status Code 429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) means you've sent too many requests in a period of time, you're being ratelimited

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community, this is about an error which doesn't need code. You cannot reproduce this unless you just spam requests. :)